# How to make attachment required field?

Tags: visualforce

How to make attachment required field.

```html
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CaseControllerExt" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:selectList styleClass="bloc" style="color:crimson;width:0px;font-size:0;border:0px;background:#f2f2f2;" size="0" value="{!Case.Subject}">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="I Need An Import" itemLabel="I Need An Import"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:inputFile accept="doc, txt, pdf" filename="{!fileName}" contentType="{!contentType}" value="{!afile}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" id="submit" action="{!createCaseWithAttachment}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: [deleting your question and re-asking it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375395/disable-submit-button-until-a-user-select-a-file) is a good way to turn off people from helping you. If you do that too much, the system itself may prevent you from making further questions.

Comment: sorry im new here and i use this site during work hours so i did not see the notifications until i turned back to work on Monday. sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below JS code to put the validation on your inputFile tag.

```
<apex:inputFile id='inputFile' value="{!attach.Body}" fileName="{!attach.name}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}" onclick='return test();'/>

<script>
     function test(){
         var inputFile = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='inputFile']")[0];
         if(inputFile.value.length === 0)
             return false;

         return true;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @B33 If this answers has solved your problem please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left (and optionally up vote it)

Comment: @B33 please mark this question as solved and upvote my answer if it helped you, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use the required attribute:

```
<apex:inputFile accept="doc, txt, pdf" 
  filename="{!fileName}" 
  contentType="{!contentType}" 
  value="{!afile}" 
  required="true" />
```